# Column Items Not Centered When the Button is Clicked in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want the Column items not centered when the button is clicked. With SingleChildScrollView "MainAxisAlignment.center" and "CrossAxisAlignment.center" doesn't work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp( MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
   MainApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
           child: Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: const Text(
                      ' Center',
                    ),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: const Text(
                      ' Center 2',
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you include full snippet that you've tried?

Comment: can you describe what exactly  you are trying to get

Comment: I want Column items not centered when the button is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to use `StatefulWidget` and you can create a state bool to control the position. If you need more control over position, try Stack widget.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool isCenter = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final body = SafeArea(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isCenter = true;
                });
              },
              child: const Text(
                ' Center',
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isCenter = false;
                });
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Not Center',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      body: isCenter
          ? Center(
              child: body,
            )
          : body,
    );
  }
}
```